# Python with WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2 refuses to start on Windows 7?

Tags: python

Under Windows 7, once installed, python.exe shows the following system error message :
"The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer."

if you know how to solve this problem please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probe installing the patch https://www.microsoft.com/es-mx/download/details.aspx?id=49093

Comment: can you try with this other ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows